# Grouping SQL Results based on order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I have table with data something like this:

```
ID     | RowNumber     | Data
------------------------------
1      | 1             | Data
2      | 2             | Data
3      | 3             | Data
4      | 1             | Data
5      | 2             | Data
6      | 1             | Data
7      | 2             | Data
8      | 3             | Data
9      | 4             | Data
```

I want to group each set of RowNumbers So that my result is something like this:

```
ID     | RowNumber     | Group | Data
--------------------------------------
1      | 1             | a     | Data
2      | 2             | a     | Data
3      | 3             | a     | Data
4      | 1             | b     | Data
5      | 2             | b     | Data
6      | 1             | c     | Data
7      | 2             | c     | Data
8      | 3             | c     | Data
9      | 4             | c     | Data
```

The only way I know where each group starts and stops is when the RowNumber starts over. How can I accomplish this? It also needs to be fairly efficient since the table I need to do this on has 52 Million Rows.

**Additional Info**

ID is truly sequential, but RowNumber may not be. I think RowNumber will always begin with 1 but for example the RowNumbers for group1 could be "1,1,2,2,3,4" and for group2 they could be "1,2,4,6", etc.

Comment: What name should the 27th group get (after `z`)?

Comment: What are you trying to find from the query?

Comment: @ypercube it doesn't matter just so long as its unique... number instead of letters would be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the clarified requirements in the comments

> The rownumbers for group1 could be "1,1,2,2,3,4" and for group2 they
>   could be "1,2,4,6" ...  a higher number followed by a lower would be a
>   new group.

A SQL Server 2012 solution could be as follows.

1. Use `LAG` to access the previous row and set a flag to `1` if that row is the start of a new group or `0` otherwise.
2. Calculate a running sum of these flags to use as the grouping value.

**Code**

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT *,
       LAG(RowNumber) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS PrevRowNumber
FROM YourTable
), T2 AS
(
SELECT *,
       IIF(PrevRowNumber IS NULL OR PrevRowNumber > RowNumber, 1, 0) AS NewGroup
FROM T1
)
SELECT ID,
        RowNumber,
        Data,
        SUM(NewGroup) OVER (ORDER BY ID 
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS  Grp
FROM T2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/03b09/2)

Assuming `ID` is the clustered index the plan for this has one scan against `YourTable` and avoids any sort operations.

[image: Plan]

Comment: I think RowNumber will always begin with 1, but it may not be truly sequential. Eg. the rownumbers for group1 could be "1,1,2,2,3,4" and for group2 they could be "1,2,4,6"

Comment: @matthew - So what denotes a new group then? A higher number followed by a lower number? What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Correct, a higher number followed by a lower would be a new group.

Comment: I'm on SQL Sever 2005. I could move the data to a SQL Server 2012 server if that is easier.

Comment: @matthew - In SQL Server 2012 it is easier as you can use `LAG` to access the previous row straight forwardly to set a flag if that row is the start of a new group then do a running total count of those flags to get the grouping value.

Answer (score 2):

If the ids are truly sequential, you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (id - rowNumber) as grp
from t
```

Comment: This looks promising. Id is truly sequential, but RowNumber may not be. Eg. group1 could equal "1,1,2,2,3,4" and group2 could be "1,2,4,6"

Comment: @matthew - If `id` is an `IDENTITY` column then "truly sequential" is not guaranteed.

Comment: @MartinSmith I know. I'm adding it to the records, so I can ensure that it truly is.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use recursive CTE

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (       
  SELECT ID, RowNumber, Data, 1 AS [Group]
  FROM dbo.test1
  WHERE ID = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.ID, t.RowNumber, t.Data, 
         CASE WHEN t.RowNumber != 1 THEN c.[Group] ELSE c.[Group] + 1 END
  FROM dbo.test1 t JOIN cte c ON t.ID = c.ID + 1
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6b01/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
select ID, RowNumber, Data, dense_rank() over (order by grp) as Grp
from (
     select *, (select min(ID) from [Your Table] where ID > t.ID and RowNumber = 1) as grp
     from [Your Table] t
) t
order by ID
```

This should work on SQL 2005. You could also use rank() instead if you don't care about consecutive numbers.